# cron jobs in MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am building an eBay-like site for auctioning. I would like to execute a few functions when the end date and the current date is zero or negative hence the items auction is ended What mechanism can query MongoDB to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've already used [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) on one of my projects. It should do the job for you.

Comment: is it efficient in terms of memory use to check the database every second or minute so that emails to winners or losers of my auction get notifications eg. emails etc?

Comment: I've used it to send emails once a week, no idea about memory efficiency but you can try it.

Comment: Check your database every 30 seconds with this cron job shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i will use AWS lambda